# Custom user authentication with Master Page in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I have a created a project in **Visual Studio 2017** using the **MasterPage**.

I have added in **MasterPage** the method **sLogins()** for user authentication.

Now I need use this method in new **Web Form** with **MasterPage**.

I have tried this without success because the method **sLogins()** is not available from **MasterPage** :

```
Mp.sLogins
```

Is not sufficient the *public* declaration of the method **sLogins()** to recall it in new **Web Form** with **MasterPage** ?

Do anyone have an idea why?

My code below.

```
public void sLogins()
{
  string username = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
  string[] strusername = username.Split('\\');

  if (strusername.Length > 0)
  {

    username = strusername[strusername.Length - 1];

    string sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM ");
    sql += String.Format(" logins ");
    sql += String.Format(" WHERE ");
    sql += String.Format(" UPPER(username) IN (?); ");

    using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQLA"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand command =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                if (username != null)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", username.ToString().ToUpper());
                    command.Connection.Open();

                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                ....
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('....');window.location='...';", true);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('....');window.location='...';", true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

New Web Form with **MasterPage**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Mp.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="Mp.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: to call the Master page function, you need to call it by (({yourMasterClass})base.Master).{func name}.

Comment: The master page function is not static, you need to reference it correctly by base.Master. then reference&apply the function by assert the base.Master as the actual Master page class

Comment: @SKLTFZ I'm sorry, but don't understand-

Comment: in case your master page is a class named Mp, you can try this (Mp(base.Master)).sLogins({params})

Comment: @SKLTFZ thanks but i have this error `CS0118: 'Mp' is 'type' but is used as 'variable'`

Comment: firstly, check if Mp is your master page class. if yes it should be something like this public partial class Mp : MasterPage in your master page class

Comment: @SKLTFZ `public partial class Mp : MasterPage` on MasterPage **Mp.master.cs**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192898/discussion-between-skltfz-and-chevy-mark-sunderland).

Comment: @SKLTFZ Solvd in chat ! Thank you so much !